# How to find any directories that match a wildcard in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

In nodejs, given a string "foo-*", how can I find all directory names that start with foo-?

E.g. The search would return foo-bar, foo-cheese etc.

What I have so far:

```
// If The directory name contains a wildcard character
// search all directory names with the preceding characters.
let wildcard = '*';
if (directory.indexOf(wildcard) !== -1) {
   // Search for directories that contain the directory string (without the *).
}
```

I couldn't see anything useful in the file system module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a low level, there's [`fs.readdir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) to read all directory entries.

You can use that to:

- read all entries in the directory you want to process
- use [`fs.stat()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) to determine if the entry is a directory
- use a module like [`minimatch`](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) to match the directory name against the pattern
- optionally recurse into the directory, if you want to match *nested* directories as well

To make your life a bit easier, you can use the [`glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) module which does all of the above.

Comment: I went with the glob module.